# Filter SOAP request base on SOAP Action in wso2 ESB

Tags: soap, wso2-esb

i have two SOAP request.so need to filter these two request using filter mediator.
how can i use soap action in filter mediator for this filtering ?

Comment: Too broad. Voting to close it.

Answer (score 0):

use property "SOAPAction" on scope "transport"

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this blog](http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2013/05/wso2-esb-filter-mediator-tutorial.html) will guide you to test filter mediator sample.